# Problems in Firefox and Chrome with "Kie Drools Workbench 6.2.0 Final" after the login

Tags: jboss, wildfly, drools, kie

I'm trying to test Kie Drools Workbench 6.2.0 Final in several web navigators (Internet Explorer , Google Chrome and Firefox ) and I'm having problems with Google Chrome and Firefox after the login, the message with the information "Please wait, loading application..." is shown but that message never dissapears and the application doesn't load.

I haven't that problem with Internet Explorer after the login but I need to test Kie Drools Workbench in the others web navigators, my operating system is Windows 7. I've tested the application in Linux (Debian) with Firefox and there is no problem after the login, the problem only happens in Windows 7, 8, 8.1 with Firefox or Chrome.

Drools workbench is deployed on WildFly AS 8, the log file shows the following registry entry when you try to access from firefox on windows 8:

> ^[[0m^[[0m08:18:18,610 INFO 
>   [org.uberfire.backend.server.plugin.RuntimePluginsServiceServerImpl]
>   (default task-1) Not listing directory content for frameworks/*.js
>   because getRealPath() is returning null. (This app is probably
>   deployed$

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: I disable AV and work fine in FF, Chorme, etc.. REF= https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jbpm-usage/QjooC_CRD4E/Cl6MO6NiEQAJ