# KIE-Workbench not loading after login

Tags: jboss, drools, wildfly, kie

Although this may be a duplicate of [Problems in Firefox and Chrome with "Kie Drools Workbench 6.2.0 Final" after the login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459595/problems-in-firefox-and-chrome-with-kie-drools-workbench-6-2-0-final-after-the) , I am posting it here again since the installation is a bit different.

I have a KIE-Workbench 6.3.0 running on a WildFly 8.2 / 9.0.1 on a Windows 2012 R2 server.

When accessing the workbench from localhost with any browser (IE, FF), everything works fine.

When accessing it remotely (IE, FF) over a fairly slow line (~5 MBit/s), I see the login screen, can enter the credentials and I can see only the "loading" screen afterwards:
[image: Firebug-screen of the non-working login]

I do not know, why the system stays in this state forever, but I do suspect the `GET A4E9BB...` request. The requested URL is `http://10.1.65.79/kie-wb/org.kie.workbench.drools.KIEDroolsWebapp/A4E9BB8E5D4AF88F8AE52E71876F3DDC.cache.js`

Due to its size of over 6 Megabytes I fear that it is some kind of timeout...

On the server side, I do not get any error messages in any log.

Does anyone have any idea on this?

Answer (score 2):

I found a - possible - solution for the moment: The almost undocumented system property `errai.bus.enable_sse_support=false` which seems (!!!) to fix our problem.

Although, judging from the semantics of the property, this looks more like a workaround than an actual solution to the underlying problem ...

The relevant hint was found in [this thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/239378) on the JBoss forums.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where the errai.bus.enable_sse_support=false fix alone did not help at all.  The switches zhrist used also did not help.  I finally found a reference to errai hanging on startup here:
[Errai client-side startup problem](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/199614?tstart=0)

That article references this SO topic:
[How to solve performance problem with Java SecureRandom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137212/how-to-solve-performance-problem-with-java-securerandom)

I plugged in the -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom property found in [Thomas Leonard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2325109/466070) alongside the list of zhrist's properties and all of a sudden Drools is logging in 100% of the time.

It seems that the loading screen may be caused by waiting for entropy in the RNG to build up, while pointing to /dev/./urandom allows it to use Pseudo-random numbers instead.  I'm not sure how this impacts any security/hashing/etc. that Drools may be employing, so be aware that this property may result in unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case. For me the solution with errai.bus.enable_sse_support=false did not help.

I had a noticeable improvement with this switches:

```
-Dorg.kie.demo=false -Dorg.kie.example=false -Derrai.bus.enable_sse_support=false 
-Dorg.uberfire.nio.git.daemon.enabled=false -Dorg.uberfire.nio.git.ssh.enabled=false
```

More you can read on [Logon hung while logging on to KIE Workbench - on Google groups forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-setup/elktCjWM520)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with jbpm-installer-7.29.0.Final.
The following worked for me:

Added two entries to build.xml under start.jboss in arg section:

```
  <arg value="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false" />
  <arg value="-Derrai.bus.enable_sse_support=false" />
```